# running python web application on aws

Tags: python, apache

I'm to use amazon web services with some python scripts I have created.
I have used PHP in the past and now I want to write a web application using python but without a web frame work such as Django (I found many tutorials for that).

While using PHP, it was enought to place my files in a dedicated directory (such as /var/www) and then the server would process them.

How is the same thing achieved with Python scripts?

What are the Django python scripts doing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It varies slightly based on the framework that you're using, but in general you need to point your web server at a `wsgi` file. For doing this with Django, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/ and http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2007/5/21/getting-started-with-wsgi/ for an overview of WSGI.

Comment: can you explain what a wsgi file is. How can i use one without django.

Comment: A WSGI file is just a Python file that defines a function called `application(environ, start_response)`, which the web server will call each time a request comes in, and will send back to the web browser whatever the function returns. Many (in fact, all) Python web toolkits (Django included) provide helpers which make it easy to write `wsgi` files.

Comment: To learn about them, see http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/learn.html and especially http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2007/5/21/getting-started-with-wsgi/

Comment: Seems that this tutorial explains how to do it.

Comment: http://theadaptiveweb.org/2011/11/04/how-to-setup-mod_wsgi-on-ec2-amazon-ami/
Any thoughts?

Comment: Glad I could help. If you like my answer, please consider upvoting and accepting it (click the checkbox below the voting arrows, on the left).

Comment: What kind of "thoughts" are you looking for?

Comment: Ah… Well, without looking too closely, I can say that it doesn't look too obviously wrong :)